# Convert .htaccess to nginx, seeking working solution

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

Hello i am aware that there are some .htaccess2nginx converter outside, and well, still need some help, since it's not working at all.

To my problem: 
Setting up an Imageboard(MyImouto) on Nginx,
Imageboard uses .htaccess to redirect from /srv/domain/public/ to /srv/domain/app/...

Here is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Images redirection.
# The following RewriteCond will try to deny any direct linking to images.
# RewriteCond %{HTTP:Referer} ^http://domain/
RewriteRule ^(?:data/)?(preview|sample|jpeg|image)/([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([$

# Serve gzipped Stylesheets and Javascripts if mod_headers are enabled.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnv no-gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^(assets/.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [L,ENV=ASSETSCSS:true] [L]
    Header set Content-Type text/css env=ASSETSCSS
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip env=ASSETSCSS
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^(assets/.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [L,ENV=ASSETSJS:true] [L]
    Header set Content-Type text/javascript env=ASSETSJS
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip env=ASSETSJS
</IfModule>

# Redirect to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Converting with one of the 3 converters i used didn't even worked.
The other both throw out something like this:

```
        rewrite ^/(?:data/)?(preview|sample|jpeg|image)/([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([$ /;
if ( ~ ""){
    set $rule_1 1$rule_1;
}
if ($rule_1 = "1"){
    rewrite / /;
}
if ( ~ ""){
    set $rule_2 1$rule_2;
}
if ($rule_2 = "1"){
    rewrite / /;
}
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_3 1$rule_3;
}
if ($rule_3 = "1"){
    rewrite /.* /index.php last;
}
```

But it's still not working.
Would be nice if you could help me for an solution :)

Comment: Your first `RewriteRule` is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand **what** this `.htaccess` do.

Except of incomplete rewrite this `.htaccess` tries to serve precompressed assets (`file.css.gz` instead of `file.css`) and rewrites requests for non-existent files to `index.php`.

I would write something like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
    # other PHP fastcgi stuff
}
```

Reference:

- [gzip_static](http://nginx.org/r/gzip_static)
- [try_files](http://nginx.org/r/try_files)

Comment: I'm never used rewrite rules manually sorry about it, and since i'm only used apache in the past it's quite hard for me to get familar with nginx. Anyways i'm really thankfull that you responded! Not just vote down and scroll on since he needs to learn how to get it himself... i'm learning but if no ones shows how this get's done well...